# Add ingress rules to aws_security_group in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm using terraform 0.7.3. I created 2 SG's and want to add ingress rules to one of them.

Workload looks like this:

```
1. $ tf plan (shows changes)
2. $ tf apply (applying changes)
```

Great, we're home... but not really :(

Next day I added another ingress rule into the template and:

```
3. $ tf plan (shows new rule we'll be added and rules from point 2 will be removed [I don't know why].
4. $ tf apply (to see what happens and some rules are removed)
5. $ tf apply (everything is updated)
```

Now I can run 'tf plan & tf apply' back in circles so things are updated but I don't understand what is breaking this.

code for rule is below:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "Web1GIngress200" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 22
  to_port                  = 22
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.Web1SG.id}"
  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.NATSG.id}"
}
```

Any advice appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the Terraform from steps 1 and 2 as well?

Comment: it shows:
~ aws_security_group.AppSG (in yellow) and list rules that will be wipe out.

I think I can't use "aws_security_group_rule" and "aws_security_group" in the same .tf file.

Comment: I was testing 'depends_on' to kind of force the order but that didn't do anything. I'm looking into other option like 'wait on' or something.

Until then any advice is really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You definitely can do that. But to see where you're going wrong you'd need to actually post all your related Terraform code.